# Why does this laravel test database insertion not work when i use a variable instead of hardcoded array?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to insert data in my test database using laravel tests. It works fine when i write the code like this:

```php
$title = "test";
$intro = "test";

$response = $this->actingAs(self::getUser(1))->post('/adm/nieuws', [
    '_token' => "6uWiMvBOVojDtT0SYvmSh9jgKCCIsZ0UE0FvbBiq",
    'title' => $title,
    'tags' => null,
    'intro' => $intro,
    'author' => 1,
    'photographer' => "test",
    'published' => "1",
    'sticky' => "1",
    'is_important' => "1",
    "pubDdate" => "2019-11-20",
    'categorySelect' => "1",
    'text' => "<p>test</p>",
    'imageUpload' => "test",
    'focuspoint' => "50%,50%",
    'imgCaption' => "test",
    'albumUpload' => ["test"],
    'albumCaptions' => ["test"],
    'zieook' => ["298"],
]);

$this->assertDatabaseHas('newsitems', [
    '_token' => "6uWiMvBOVojDtT0SYvmSh9jgKCCIsZ0UE0FvbBiq",
    'title' => $title,
    'tags' => null,
    'intro' => $intro,
    'author' => 1,
    'photographer' => "test",
    'published' => "1",
    'sticky' => "1",
    'is_important' => "1",
    "pubDdate" => "2019-11-20",
    'categorySelect' => "1",
    'text' => "<p>test</p>",
    'imageUpload' => "test",
    'focuspoint' => "50%,50%",
    'imgCaption' => "test",
    'albumUpload' => ["test"],
    'albumCaptions' => ["test"],
    'zieook' => ["298"],
]);
```

This looks a bit messy so i'm trying to make it better by first putting the data into an array, then inserting and checking if it is inserted. when i run my test i get this error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'where clause'. This doesnt make sense to me because its the same data.

```php
$title = "test";
$intro = "test";

$data = [
    '_token' => "6uWiMvBOVojDtT0SYvmSh9jgKCCIsZ0UE0FvbBiq",
    'title' => $title,
    'tags' => null,
    'intro' => $intro,
    'author' => 1,
    'photographer' => "test",
    'published' => "1",
    'sticky' => "1",
    'is_important' => "1",
    "pubDdate" => "2019-11-20",
    'categorySelect' => "1",
    'text' => "<p>test</p>",
    'imageUpload' => "test",
    'focuspoint' => "50%,50%",
    'imgCaption' => "test",
    'albumUpload' => ["test"],
    'albumCaptions' => ["test"],
    'zieook' => ["298"],
];

$response = $this->actingAs(self::getUser(1))->post('/adm/nieuws', $data);

$this->assertDatabaseHas('newsitems', $data);
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: What if you remove the `_token` from the `$data` array?

Comment: because the `_token` is probably getting removed before insertion in the code ... `_token` is the CSRF token, it wouldn't be inserted into any table, it is just part of the request